# Issues with Embedding Videos and the Open graph protocol

Tags: video, facebook-opengraph

Our members have been able to embed videos from our site (http://exposureroom.com) into their Facebook pages, util about 3 days ago.

Now they see some weird things such as Object Moved or a link to our home page.

Using the Facebook linter at http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug and a sample page

http://exposureroom.com/members/skumar/1bc6b78507f34a008a921468947757e2/

I see that for some reason the issue revolves around re-directs. The link above is the permanent url (no-redirects) for the resource. The og:url meta tag within the above page also points to the exact same url. However the linter reports it as

http://exposureroom.com/members//1bc6b78507f34a008a921468947757e2/

Notice the member name "skumar" has gone missing, even though the actual url in the og:url tag on the page has the correct url.

Another thing to note is that on our site, if the url provided is invalid, the system will re-direct to the home page. So because the linter is seeing an invalid url it eventually gets redirected to the home page.

So I don't understand why even though the og:url tag has the correct url, the linter sees it as a different url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this manually and your og:url tag was indeed set to `http://exposureroom.com/members//1bc6b78507f34a008a921468947757e2/`

Check the code path that populates the variable with the value 'skumar' - it must not be firing for the linter's request.

Here's what i checked:

```
curl -A "facebookexternalhit/1.1" -i \
"http://exposureroom.com/members/skumar/1bc6b78507f34a008a921468947757e2/" | grep meta
```

And the response (i've included only the open graph meta tags):

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://exposureroom.com/members//1bc6b78507f34a008a921468947757e2/" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Builder for ASP.NET - Data Binding" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" /><meta property="og:site_name" content="ExposureRoom" />
<meta property="og:author" content="Shiv Kumar" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://img1.exposureroom.com/thumbnails/getassetthumbnailimage/1bc6b78507f34a008a921468947757e2/sm/" />
<meta property="og:description" content="In this video you&#39;ll see how the data binding features work in Builder for ASP.NET" /><meta property="og:video" content="http://exposureroom.com/flash/XRVideoPlayer2.swf?assetId=1bc6b78507f34a008a921468947757e2&amp;size=sm" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="270" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="480" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
```

Comment: @lgy, thanks for the prompt reply. I don't understand what you mean by manually. If I do a view source on the page I can see that the og:url is as expected. I think I understand the problem better since you're seeing this with curl. I'll check it with Fiddler or access that page using another (non browser) tool to see what I get.

Comment: Ok, the can reproduce the problem with Fiddler as well and can see what is going on. Thanks for your help! I should have thought about using Fiddler...